# Devices are not found when executing command (but "fastboot devices" finds them)

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, nexus-4

I'm trying to install CyanogenMod on **Nexus 4** and so far I had done this:
- installed google driver;
- enabled developer options on my phone;
- enabled debugging by USB;
- unlocked my device using ADB;
- installed CyanogenMod Recovery;

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools> .\fastboot flash recovery .\cm-13.0-20160510-NIGHTLY-mako-
recovery.img
```

- started bootloader;

Then I get the following error trying to push the file to the devuce:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools> .\fastboot devices
01cf8682d9c98ac0        fastboot
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools> .\adb push cm-13.0-20160510-NIGHTLY-mako.zip /sdcard
error: device '(null)' not found
```

I followed [CyanogenMod instructions](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mako) step-by-step, including troubleshooting section, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: `adb` is not the same as `fastboot`. Thus, if `adbd` is not running on the device, `adb` can't find it. The same applies to `fastboot`.

Comment: You cannot use ADB when you are at the bootloader, you would need to push the files to the device using ADB when in recovery.

Comment: Don't edit the question to include the solution, because then the question will always show up as unanswered. Instead, "answer your own question" and then accept the answer you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This works from Recovery mode:
- Full factory reset
and then:
- Apply Update -> From ADB

```
.\adb sideload cm-13.0-20160510-NIGHTLY-mako.zip
```